# VB 6.0, take input from user and open a folder

Tags: vb6

i want to take 2 input from user and open folder

Suppose we have several  directory  like G:\s\ABC-123\XYZ-001 
i want to take 2 input from user where user will give input of 123 and 001 in different textbox and folder will open.
G:\s\ABC-(string)\XYZ-(string)
where string are the input from user.

i have got this code on internet,can you guys help me with this.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Function pathOfFile(fileName As String) As String
    Dim posn As Integer
    posn = InStrRev(fileName, "\")
    If posn > 0 Then
        pathOfFile = Left$(fileName, posn)
    Else
        pathOfFile = ""
    End If
End Function
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "D:\Dani\result.png"
    ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, pathOfFile(myPath), vbNullString, vbNullString, 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Meaning, what is wrong with what you have tried so far?

Comment: The " " and the & i have been doing it wrong

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have 2 textbox controls on your form, your challenge is how to put together your path.  Try the following:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "G:\s\ABC-" & Text1.Text & "\XYZ-" & Text2.Text
    ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, pathOfFile(myPath), vbNullString, vbNullString, 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. 
i was stucked between  " " and the & symbol.